# CiviCRM OG Sync documentation

Tags: drupal

The link listed in the CIVICRM panel of `http://www.example.com/admin/modules` is http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviCRM+vs.+Organic+Groups. This results in a 404.

The only other documentation I have found is a brief [2013 wiki article](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Organic+Groups+CiviCRM+Synchronization). Is anything else available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/#civicrm-organic-groups-sync

I'll look into getting that updated. Thanks for reporting.

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/drupal/issues/102